# Polymer how to re-render element/template

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to dynamically add a page to `iron-pages`, but the element doesn't recognize the dynamically added content. I think this happen during html rendering, but I don't know how to trigger it again. The jsbin below demonstrates what I'm trying to do: http://jsbin.com/nuhone/4/edit?html,console,output. Basically, I have an `iron-pages` with one existing page. I'm trying to add a second page dynamically, but unable to do so because `iron-pages` doesn't recognize this newly added `div`.

Comment: I don't think `iron-pages` and other similar polymer elements can actually recognize when new childs are appended to them, I think your best shot is to use a `dom-repeat` in the `iron-pages` and push the new elements to its items array

Comment: @Alan lemme try to confirm if it works. Sounds like a promising idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took a look at your code - basically 2 issues.

1. **Polymer.domAPI**

   When inserting or removing nodes, use it.
2. **Race Condition**

   `iron-pages` extends `IronSelectableBehavior` - ie *MutationObservers* have already been setup nicely to detect whenever you add/remove pages. However, this takes time to trigger. Wrap your next steps with `Polymer.async()` to place them at the end of the microtasks queue.

   ```
   document.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", function() {
     var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
     newDiv.innerHTML = "Def";
     var ironPage = document.querySelector("iron-pages");
     Polymer.dom(ironPage).appendChild(newDiv);
     Polymer.Base.async(function () {
       console.log(ironPage.items.length); // shows 2
       ironPage.select(1);
     });
   });
   ```

Your jsbin fixed: http://jsbin.com/viqunoxesi/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 0):

It might help to use the Polymer DOM API like

```
Polymer.dom(document.querySelector("iron-pages"))
  .appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: I tried that with my jsbin but couldn't get it to work :(